# Session specific tables in SqlServer other than Temp tables

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create tables in Sql Server which are session specific but should not have the prefix "#" in it. The reason for this is I have some predefined queries which cannot be changed now with specific table names. I was using SqlCE till now and would like to migrate to SqlServer for performance reason. Please provide your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a synonym for your temp table (available since SQL Server 2008).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Example:

```
create table #test (test_id int, test_name nvarchar(64))

insert into #test (test_id, test_name) values (1, 'Jonn Doe')

create synonym test for #test

select * from test
```